# Why does a numeric key in the JSON Structure always get displayed first

Tags: json, angular, typescript

(Cannot summarize the problem in a single statement, hence the ambiguous title)

I create a JSON structure via **Angular Typescript**, wherein when a user interacts with certains parts of the component the JSON Structure gets updated.

#### Steps

1. Initially, the JSON under consideration is by default set to the following:

   ```
   {
     "keyword": {
     "value": "product",
      "type": "main"
      }
   }
   ```
2. For example, a user chooses some parameter `Name`. Once the user complies to certain steps in the UI, the JSON structure gets updated to the following:

   ```
   {
     "keyword": {
     "value": "product",
     "type": "main"
     },
      "Name": {
      "value": " <hasProperty> Name",
      "type": "dataprop"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Once the user selects a numeric value for a parameter like `dryTime`, the JSON gets updated to the following:

   ```
   {
      "20": { // WHY WOULD 20 be here?
      "value": "<hasValue> 20",
      "type": "fValue"
      },
      "keyword": {
       "value": "Varnish",
       "type": "main"
      },
      "Name": {
      "value": " <hasProperty> Name",
      "type": "dataprop"
      },
     "dryingTime": {
     "value": " <hasProperty> dryingTime",
     "type": "dataprop"
      }
   }
   ```

I understand that a JSON is an *unordered* data structure. But a previous implementation of something similar actually worked well, i.e., the value `20` here was `20.0` before and it was displayed after `dryingTime` in my JSON.

The order is critical for me as I parse all the Keys in the above mentioned JSON using a `for` loop and store it in an array. This array needs to show all the keys in the order of the User Interaction.

Where am I going wrong here if I decide to stay with JSON and not with an array to store such interactions?

Comment: As you said, JSON is unordered, if you want the data to be exactly what you want you pretty much need to structure it in arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JSON fields are unordered. JSON array is ordered.

If you want to keep the order of elements insterted, you could build your JSON like so:

```
{
    "keyword": {
        "value": "Varnish",
        "type": "main"
    },
    "props": [
        {
            "name": "dryingTime",
            "value": 20
        },
        {
            "name": "anotherOrderedField",
            "value": "fieldValue"
        }
    ]
}
```